# Send content to WordPress' plain text editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg, text-editor

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that allows sending a short code into the rich text editor. Assuming the short code content is stored inside `shortcode` variable, the following code works perfectly:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, shortcode);
```

...if the user is in "Visual Editor" mode. If they switch to "Plain Text" mode, the code doesn't work anymore - no content appears in the textarea.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

(Ah, if that matters, I have several instance of editors on the same "Add Post" page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got it! Simply do

```
send_to_editor(shortcode);
```

this function is located inside media-upload.js, which should be loaded in Edit/Add Post pages.